# Prove equivalence kernel of an injection is the identity relation

Tags: equivalence-relations, quotient-set

Given a function $f$  and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on the domain of $f$, if two equivalent elements with respect to $\sim$ have the same image under $f$, then $\sim$ is called the **equivalence kernel of $f$**

In other words  $\sim$ is the equivalence kernel of $f$ if and only if for any $x_1,x_2 \in D_f$:
$$x_1\sim x_1⇔f\left(x_{1}\right)=f\left(x_{2}\right)$$

For example the quotient mapping of a set $X$ defined as  $\pi:X \to X/\sim$  is a function such that for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$:   $$x_1 \sim x_2 ⇔\left[x_{1}\right]=\left[x_{2}\right]$$ 
or equivalently :   $$x_1 \sim x_2 ⇔\pi(x_{1})=\pi(x_{2})$$

Where $ \left[a\right]$ is the equivalence class of $a$.

Using definition of an equivalence kernel it follows  $\sim$ is actually
the  equivalence kernel of  $\pi$

> As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) says the equivalence kernel of an injection is the identity relation.

By definition $f:X\to Y$ is injection if and only if: $$f(x_1)=f(x_2)⇒x_1=x_2$$

the equivalence kernel of $f$ would be the equivalence relation $=$
but we also should show that the other direction  $$x_1=x_2⇒f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$ holds.

I think this direction is clear, but I'm not sure about that, because maybe there is another reason for that .

And also I don't know how exactly identity relation will help us ( maybe it's for proving the other direction I'm looking for)
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

For *every* function, we have$$x_1=x_2\implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$and therefore $f$ is injective if and only if$$x_1=x_2\iff f(x_1)=f(x_2).$$So, if you define $x_1\sim x_2$ as $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $f$ is injective if and only if $\sim$ is the identity relation.

Comment: can you say what is the definition of an identity relation? as I know identity relation is a homogeneous binary relation , e.g. a subset of the Cartesian product of two sets that are the same set, but why $x_1=x_2\iff f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ defines an identity relation (with relation "equality")

Comment: **The** identity relation is $x\sim y\iff x=y$.

Comment: I'm really sorry for not understanding, but why we do't say " the equivalence kernel for an injection is $=$'?because the equivalence defied on the domain of an injection is the equivalence relation "equality"

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what is it that you don't understand.

Comment: When we define a function as a quotient mapping of a set $X$ we know that for every two arbitrary elements is $X$ there is an equivalence relation $∼$ between them iff their equivalence classes are the same set, the binary relation that makes this construction $\color{red}{x_1∼x_2\iff \pi(x_1)=\pi(x_2)}$ is $$\color{blue}{∼}$$ ( as I said let the function to be defined as a quotient mapping of X), in your proof the binary relation that let us to have $\color{red}{x_1=x_2\iff f(x_1)=f(x_2)}$ is $$\color{blue}{=}$$ so why we don't say $=$ is the equivalence kernel of an injective function ?

Comment: Because that relation has a name: “identity”. Saying that the answer is $=$ is like talking about “the function $e^x$” instead of talking about “the exponential function”: it makes sense, but it looks weird.